# Adding a row to a DataGridView clears existing rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am trying to add rows to a DataGridView but it seems to be setting the cell values of all previous rows to Nothing whenever a new row is added.

I do this all the time but it's not working in this new project - is this some bug or am I missing something obvious? (much more likely!)

My code:

```
DG = DataGridView

lstOrders = List(Of mystructure)

    Private Sub PopulateGrid()
        DG.Rows.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To lstOrders.Count - 1
            DG.Rows.Add()

            With DG.Rows(DG.Rows.Count - 1)
                .Cells(ColUsername.Index).Value = "abc" 'test
                'etc
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
```

The cell values get filled fine, but when it gets to the `DG.Rows.Add()` the previous row all gets set to Nothing.

What's going on?

Comment: That `Add` method returns the index of the row just added.  I would tend to use that to access the row in the next section of code.  Try that and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That fixed it, thank you!  I also found that I had adding/editing/deleting still enabled, when I disabled those then my original method started working.  Odd.

Comment: Not odd at all. If the user is allowed to add rows then the last row in the grid is the data entry row. Your original code was populating the last row in the grid, so not the row you added but the data entry row. By using the index returned by `Add` you ensure that you access the row just added, regardless of anything else.

Comment: Please accept the answer provided below so that anyone who finds this question with a similar issue will quickly find the correct answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, the solution is to use the index returned by `Add` to ensure that you always access the row just added.  The index used originally may or may not have referred to the same row, depending on circumstances.